# Unexpected end of JSON input : SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, api

I keep getting Unexpected end of JSON input error when I test and it keeps crashing

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Messages from './dbMessages.js'

const app = express ()
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.use(express.json());

const connection_url = '...'

mongoose.connect(connection_url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

app.get('/', (req, res)=> res.status(200).send('hello world'))

app.get('/messages/sync', (req, res) => {
    Messages.find((err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(data)
        }
    })
})

app.post('/messages/new', (req, res) => {
    const dbMessage = req.body

    Messages.create(dbMessage, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
            res.status(201).send(data)
        }
    })
})

app.listen(port, ()=>console.log(`Listening on localhost:${port}`))
```

with all these I don't know why I keep getting an error each time I test the get method using postman,

Comment: There isn't enough information here. What response do you actually get? Please add to your question.

Comment: Can u elaborate more? What is "Messages" ?

Comment: Which http code do you get?

Comment: It seems your response is not jsonified. http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

Comment: We need to see what the actual response is, as that is likely where the issue is.

Comment: when I tested http://localhost:9000/messages/sync, using get, I got  an Unexpected end of JSON input error and I don't seem to know where there was a json input error

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely coming from the client side. Do check the format of your data from the client side. For example, if you are using postman to test, make sure you do not add a comma at the end of your json data.